# Execute js code inside a ajax handler function in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I focused on a wordpress plugin development. In this plugin, I'm trying to design a progress bar that moves according a backend process. After an extensive search, I understood that it is possible by using jquery methods.

From [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) reference, I wrote following code in plugin's main php file:

```
<?php
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'my_action_javascript' );

function my_action_javascript() { ?>
<script type="text/javascript" >
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var element = document.getElementById("myBar"); // It is my bootstrap progress bar
    var width=0; // Initial width (%)
    var add=1; // 1% incrementation variable for progress bar

    var data = {
        'action': 'my_action',
        'whatever': 1234
    };
    
    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    });
});
</script> <?php
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );

function my_action() {

$whatever = $_POST['whatever'];

echo $whatever;

wp_die();
}
```

It works fine, the response shows on alert field. However, when I add following js code into that `my_action` function:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );

function my_action() {

$repeater = 0;
$controller = 0;

for ($i=1; $i <= 4000 ; $i++) { 
    if ($repeater <= 10) {
        $controller++;
        if ($controller == 40) { ?>
            //code starts here
            <script type="text/javascript">
            element.style.width = width + add + "%"; 
            element.innerHTML = width + add + "%";
            width = width+add;  
            </script>
            <?php 
            sleep(1);
            $controller=0;
            $repeater++;
        }
    } else {
        return;
    }
}

wp_die();
}
```

It doesn't work. I guess the nature of ajax process in wordpress, the core is waiting for finishes all php codes in function and it doesn't allow run another js code. So, if I miss some point or there is a better way to achieve this; I would be grateful if you help.

Comment: javascript ajax requests work as "request"->"response".   A single request will provide a single response.  There's no "partial" response.  You might like to look into [tag:websocket] which keeps an "open" connection between the js and the backend.

Comment: "*it doesn't allow run another js code*" - this isn't strictly true - you can run any other *js* code you like (assuming your ajax is async).  The js is *waiting* for the (full) response from the server - it's your service that isn't returning.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve.
It seems to me that you are trying to change the size of a html element via javascript in a way that it became bigger in steps, so some kind of animation.
To do that you can't mix javascript and php (at least in that way) and you don't need the mix, just use javascript.
On php side, you do not need such compliated increments, it can be made much simpler.
On javascript you have element, did you assign a dom element to that var as global?
Did you define the value for add? otherwise you are always adding null (which is 0)

Comment: @freedomn-m It's true. I know the request-response concept but i need multiple responses in my case. Otherwise, it will be useless for progress bar.

Comment: @RobertoBraga The code in function "my_action" is just for representative. The reason that i wanna mix php and javascript is; I have wordpress core functions such as 'wp_set_object_terms' , 'update_post_meta' in "my_action" function. So I have to use php. On the other hand, I should use javascript to trigger the progress bar.

Comment: @RobertoBraga Briefly, I'm working on a woocommerce product integration plugin. Because the product attributes coming from 3rd party API, I need to create a custom plugin to add products and synchronize them.

Comment: @RobertoBraga Yes, as it shows in shared code, i choose my bar element and also i created variables called 'width' and 'add' before the ajax call. Even if I use just simple alert('hello'); instead above code , it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i think of one of the many plugins in wordpress that does something similar  i always found that they divide the task in very small "chunks".
For every chunk they make a new ajax call, get a response, update the progress bar and repeat, until the full task is over.

In your case say that you have 100 products to import you should split them in like 10 request with 10 item each and return the updated % accordingly.

This design is much more easier to implements and it could give better UX to the user

Comment: In this case, i think this seems the best way to do it. Even if there are thousands of products and very long function, i have to divide it somehow.

Comment: If you have thousands of products then i guess you would reach a point where you would need to divide them anyways since you would run out of execution time and setting that to -1 in PROD isn't a good idea :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to flush after every <script>

try to add before sleep()

```
ob_flush();
flush();
sleep(1);
```

if you don't flush, all the output is sent at the end of the execution or when outptbuffer is full.

That means that now you send all script at once

Comment: I tried but sadly, nothing happened. It didn't return any action.